# Solve $56x+63y=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve $56x+63y=1$

What I did:

$$\gcd(56,63):$$

$$\qquad63=56\cdot 1+7\\56=7\cdot 8$$

$$\Longrightarrow \gcd=7$$

Since $7\nmid 1$ there is no solution, but I think that [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=56x%2B63y%3D1) says something else

Comment: You are right: it's Bezout condition. But what "says" the oracle Wolfram Alpha ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't *integer* solutions, in other words you cannot find a couple of integer satisfying the equation. However that equation describe a line on the plane, so if you are looking for rational or real solution, these are infinite.

Answer (score 1):

"In mathematics, a **Diophantine equation** is a polynomial equation, usually in two or more unknowns, such that only the integer solutions are sought or studied"

**See** [Linear Congruence Theroem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Error404, I can open the link : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem.  Try https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence

Comment: @Error404 works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be rewritten as $7(8x+9y)=1$ so $$8x+9y = \frac{1}{7}.$$
Whether this equation has any solutions depends on from which domain you take $x$ and $y$ to be. The way your question is written sort of implies that you want $x,y$ to be whole numbers. Then the above equation immediately implies that there won't be any solutions since $8x+9y$ will always be a whole number and $\frac{1}{7}$ isn't. This same argument can be extended to show that equations of the form
$$
a x + b y = 1
$$
have no integer solutions for $x,y$ if $\gcd(a,b)>1$. On the other hand, the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) shows that you can always find integers $x,y$ such that 
$$
ax+by = \gcd(a,b).
$$
Wolfram interprets the domain of $x,y$ to be the real numbers. In this case there are an infinite amount of solutions to the equation and they represent a line in the plane.